# can we set different cursor idle timeout per query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Please, advice how to set the cursor idle timeout to some bigger values for only certain queries to  avoid the default threshold  of 10 min that is working perfectly well for all other queries ?
(I see the only option seems to be  to set for those long running queries the db.col.find().noCursorTimeout() , but wondering if it can be customized per query or at least group of queries  )

Comment: From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.maxTimeMS/ : "For operations that return a cursor, if the cursor may be idle for longer than 30 minutes, issue the operation within an explicit session using Session.startSession() and periodically refresh the session using the refreshSessions command." Would that work for you?